# arrayformula seems to only work at top nesting level

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, array-formulas

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(B2:B),"",B2:B))
```

duplicates the column. But,

```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(B2:B),"",CONCATENATE("B=",B2:B)))
```

produces a column with values starting with `B=` , but followed by the juxtaposition of all the row values from the B column in each cell of the result column.

It seems that the effect of B2:B on the left, even though it is two nesting levels down, produces the right result (values only if column B is not blank in each row), but the effect of B2:B on the right, has a different effect, and varies according to conditions I don't understand, sometimes being a single value, and sometimes expanded to a whole array. This makes `ARRAYFORMULA` have extremely limited usefulness for my application. I was hoping the resulting column would have only a single value from the corresponding row of column B.

Am I missing something about how to use `ARRAYFORMULA` ?

Is there a different way to achieve my goal of adding `B=` at the front of each cell in the result column? (Actually, my goal is to do more sophisticated combinations of the cell value and other text, but I reduced it down to this much simpler case which I don't understand, and maybe if I figure this out, I can do the more complex stuff too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CONCATENATE` merges all arrays to a single value. I believe this is what you're  looking for:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(B2:B="","",("B="&B2:B)))
```

Here's some food for thought. What do you expect the following formula to do?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(if(isblank(B2:B),"",("B="&B2:B&""))))
```

Also Try `CONCAT`, `JOIN` and `TEXTJOIN`. Each might look doing the same. But those subtle differences make all the difference in the world.

Comment: Yes, use of CONCAT rather than CONCATENATE solved my problems, and allowed me to do the more complex stuff too. Thanks.